# Write JSON to a file with CFFile Action Append

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cffile

Is there any way to keep the last line of a text file when using the `cffile` action APPEND?

I am trying to write to a `.txt` file in JSON like format. So, I created a variable with everything I need:

```
<cfset output = ',
                {
                "Type" : "Succes",    
                "login" : "#dateFormat(now(), 'DD/MM/YYYY')#",
                "user" : "#user#",
                }
                 '>
```

and after that I use:

```
<cffile action="APPEND" 
file="\test.txt"
output="#output#" fixnewline="yes">
```

The problem is that when I write the file the new JSON element gets written after the end square bracket `]` and normally the JSON becomes unreadable. Does someone know if I can write to a specific line or keep the last line when I'm using `cffile` with append.

Comment: Not sure I am following you. Where is the square bracket `]` coming from? Is it already in the file? If so, as the action you are using says, it will _append_ to the end of the file. There is no automated way to insert text into an existing file. You would need to read in the file and process the contents in some way to place the text where you want it. And then write the file over.

Comment: Yep.  Instead of rolling your own JSON, why not just read in the contents, deserialize, append whatever data you want and overwrite the file?

Comment: @Miguel-F The ] is already in the file, and yes, i wanted some sort of automated process to read the file and append the new content just before ] tag.

Comment: @Ageax  I want to add new content not overwrite the file.and serialize the content will do the same thing.i need to insert new content not overwrite.

Comment: @user1673306 - Think you misunderstood. I'm suggesting load the *existing* contents, add your new data, then save the whole thing back to the file.